# Visual feedback in customized ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've adapted the standard ExpandableListView to use my own indicator image so I can remove it when a group has no children. I also made some changes that the text views in the group view have a separate OnClickListener to show some details about the group. Clicking on the indicator icon will expand/collapse the group as usual.

My question is how do I get the same visual feedback (shift in background color to blue and back) on clicking the text views of a group as I get when clicking the indicator icon or a child row?

My group layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_group_timestamp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_group_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_group_exp_indicator"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/news_group_expander" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The relevant portions of the adapter are listed below. The `ViewHolder` is a simple class to support various group types (section header or actual group item).

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    convertView = createGroupView(groupPosition);
    fillGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView);

    return convertView;
}

protected class OnTextClickListener implements OnClickListener
{
    protected int m_groupPosition;

    public OnTextClickListener(int groupPosition)
    {
        m_groupPosition = groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        ...
    }
}

protected View createGroupView(int groupPosition)
{
    View view = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_group, null);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.groupExpIndicator = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_group_exp_indicator);

    // We set the OnClickListener for the timestamp and title views so we
    // can use this to show the details of a group item. The expansion of
    // the group is handled higher up where the indicator click is
    // processed.

    holder.groupTimestampView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_group_timestamp);
    holder.groupTimestampView.setOnClickListener(new OnTextClickListener(groupPosition));

    holder.groupTitleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_group_title);
    holder.groupTitleView.setOnClickListener(new OnTextClickListener(groupPosition));

    view.setTag(holder);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: do you want to change color of the `ExpandableListView` when pressed or on the `textView` of the `parentView` click event?

Comment: @rohan I want to get the same visual feedback when pressing the `TextView`s as I get when pressing any other item in the `ExpandableListView`. I did some more digging (now going from the other side) and found that I probably need to change the `TextView` to a borderless `Button` to get the same feedback.

Comment: you can use `ImageButtons` with background set as `#0000` i.e. transparent. And i really don't understand what you want, perhaps you can show a picture showing your problem?

Comment: @rohan I've tried using `Button` but the result is that only the background of the button shows the click feedback, not the complete row. I've also tried using the `OnTouchListener` but that didn't really work as well.

Comment: @rohan I've something like "<text><longer text><indicator>" for each group and with normal `ExpandableListView` behaviour when I click the row the group will expand and visual feedback (changed background) is visible for the complete row. I've changed the behaviour so that a click on the texts will show additional information and only when clicking the indicator will expand the group. Now I get visual feedback only when I click the indicator and the feedback is restricted to the area of the indicator. No visual feedback is given when I click on either of the texts.

Comment: I am not getting you can you provide a image as to what you want? I will help

Comment: a rough image will do.